# Obtain names from foreign key relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I would like to alter my query result to give me a different result for example

when I run this query

```
select *
from receipt
where receiptId = 358914592`
```

It gives me a table like this

| receiptId | date | price | salesRep | PatientId | stat | reqDoc | reviewwee | patho | medtech |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 358914592 | 2023-06-21 | 1200 | NULL | 1023957457 | done | dr. Dave | 10111012317 | 64242 | 32347 |

I want the query to show the names of the pathologist, reviewee and medtech rather than their primary keys

like this

| receiptId | date | price | salesRep | PatientId | stat | reqDoc | reviewwee | patho | medtech |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 358914592 | 2023-06-21 | 1200 | NULL | 1023957457 | done | dr. Dave | nurse Joy | Dr. Hawk browns | michaela jose |

Comment: And to get names you'll have to join on the tables that contain the names - which you haven't showed us - but should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Foreign keys do not push or pull data, you need to join for this..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use Joins in order to display that information.

```sql
select receiptId, date, price, patient,..., path.name...
from receipt as rec
join pathologist as path on rec.pathId = path.Ud
where receiptId = 358914592`
```

Comment: i'll try this one

Comment: No problem! Hope I helped you in your journey into `JOINS`